# Unable to Send Kafka Messages with EmbeddedKafka in Spring Boot3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-boot-3, spring-kafka-test

I am facing an issue with my Spring Boot application (version **3.2.1**) and Embedded Kafka. The problem is that the KafkaTemplate is not successfully sending messages

Here is my test code

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092" }, controlledShutdown = true)
public class PaymentITest {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

    @Value("${demo.kafka.topic.payment}")
    private String topicName;

    @Test
    void test() {
        String jsonPayload = "{ \"payload\": { \"payment_id\": \"1\" } }";

        kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, "key", jsonPayload);
    }
}
```

**The Kafka Consumer **

```java
import fr.test.test.compute.common.event.PaymentEvent;
import fr.test.test.compute.core.domain.port.api.PaymentRequester;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaPaymentConsumer {

    private final PaymentRequester paymentRequester;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${demo.kafka.topic.payment}'}",
                   groupId = "#{'${demo.kafka.group-id}'}")
    public void consumePaymentEvents(PaymentEvent paymentEvent)  {
        paymentRequester.handlePaymentReceivedEvent(paymentEvent.extractModel());
    }

}
```

**test/resources/application.yml**

```
spring:
  mongodb:
    embedded:
      storage:
        oplogSize: 10
        repl-set-name: rs0
      version: "5.0.5"
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      group-id: kafka-group-id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      enable-auto-commit: false
      properties:
        spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: fr.test.test.compute.config.kafka.KafkaEventDeserializer
    producer:
      bootstrap.servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: fr.test.test.compute.config.kafka.KafkaEventSerializer

de:
  flapdoodle:
    mongodb:
      embedded:
        version: 4.0.2

demo:
  kafka:
    topic:
      payment: payment_topic2
    group-id: kafka-group
```

I already tested with a local kafka broker, the consumer works well !

but when running the test, I added a breakpoint in the consumer, and this last is not being hit ! what could be causing the KafkaTemplate not to send messages (as shown in the picture below) ?  Is it an issue related to Kafka Embedded in SpringBoot 3

Here is the Github repository  for the code base https://github.com/smaillns/springboot-mongo-kafka

Any suggestions would be appreciated ?

[image]

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@bfc918c[Not completed]
```

Comment: I just added a link to a Github project

Comment: the test https://github.com/smaillns/springboot-mongo-kafka/blob/main/src/test/java/com/example/demo/TestITest.java

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to comment out `bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092` in test resources `application.yml`?. I have had similar problem and this helped me, otherwise my app was trying to call my Kafka in Docker.